# Curtin installer failing

Tags: maas, curtin

Trying to provision a server, and it fails with the error below. It isn't clear why. I grep'd `/etc/maas/preseeds` for `block-meta` and `simple` and found neither. So I'm not sure when/where this is getting called. I've provisioned over a dozen servers this week w/o any issues. It's unclear why this one is failing.

```
list index out of range
Installation failed with exception: Unexpected error while running command.
Command: ['curtin', 'block-meta', 'simple']
Exit code: 3
Reason: -
Stdout: 'list index out of range\n'
Stderr: ''
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual command that performs this operation is built into curtin in the partitioning_commands. Curtin by default will call "curtin block-meta simple". The command searches for a disk to perform the installation on, the error you are seeing is because your system has no disks that curtin can install to. Make sure that the system you are deploying to has a disk that is writeable.

If you system does have a disk present, this most likely means that the kernel is unable to enumerate this storage device. You can try a hardware enablement kernel to see if drivers for your device are available in a newer kernel. Set the architecture on a node to "amd64/hwe-u" or higher to get a newer kernel. If this still does not work then it means your need some other driver enablement to allow the curtin to be able to install to your device.

I have documented this information in [bug 1451490](https://bugs.launchpad.net/curtin/+bug/1451490) as well.